# SelectedItem of a variable combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

There is a combobox which i fill with this loop

```
foreach (Machine.Types machine in machineList)
{
    cbMachineGUI.Items.Add(machine);
}
```

after that i want the selected index to be one specific machine.

```
string machineComboBox = SettingsManager.getParameter("MachineType");
cbMachineGUI.SelectedItem = machineComboBox;
```

The parameter is correct and set, but the selecteditem of the combobox is always nothing.

if i set the machines in the properties of the combobox (not via the loop) it works. but i need the combobox to be variable.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that what you put in `Items` and what you set `SelectedItem` to are different types.

You are filling the `Items` collection with `Machine.Types` instances, and setting `SelectedItem` to a `string` instance.

Using `IndexOf` like other answers suggest will not help, as this will not do anything that setting `SelectedItem` does not already do. It still won't find `machineComboBox` in the `Items` collection, just like it can't find it now.

You need to use matching types, so do **one** of these things (depending on how else you use the values in the combobox):

1. Convert `Machine.Types` to a `string` when filling the collection:

   ```
   cbMachineGUI.Items.Add(machine.ToString());
   ```
2. Convert `machineComboBox` into an instance of `Machine.Types` that will match the one in `Items` when setting `SelectedItem` - how to do it depends on what `Machine.Types` is
3. Find the correct item yourself when setting `SelectedItem`:

   ```
   cbMachineGUI.SelectedItem = cbMachineGUI.Items
                                           .OfType<Machine.Types>()
                                           .FirstOrDefault(item => item.ToString() == machineComboBox);
   ```

Either way, you must make a conversion between these two types *somewhere*.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting SelectedItem, I suggest you find the item's index and set the selected index.

Something like this:

```
string machineComboBox = SettingsManager.getParameter("MachineType");
int itemIndex = cbMachineGUI.Items.IndexOf(machineComboBox);
cbMachineGUI.SelectedIndex = itemIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
cbMachineGUI.SelectedIndex = cbMachineGUI.Items.IndexOf("MachineType"); // or whatever you want to select
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be possible that the item you are trying to set doesn't present in combobox item list and since you haven't actually selected anything it sets to nothing. To check if the item does exist do below

```
string machineComboBox = SettingsManager.getParameter("MachineType");
if(cbMachineGUI.Items.IndexOf(machineComboBox) >= 0)
 cbMachineGUI.SelectedItem = machineComboBox;
```

Quoting from MSDN documentation:

> When you try to set the SelectedItem property to an object, the
>   ComboBox attempts to make that object the currently selected one in
>   the list. If the object is found in the list, it is displayed in the
>   edit portion of the ComboBox and the SelectedIndex property is set to
>   the corresponding index. If the object does not exist in the list, the
>   SelectedIndex property is left at its current value.The ComboBox class
>   searches for the specified object by using the IndexOf method.

Check [ComboBox.SelectedItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more information.